# Filtering a bound listbox c#

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, listbox

I have a XAML file tha contains a listbox and a textbox.

The listbox is filled with databinding like so:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstboxNotes"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNote}"
        Grid.Row="1"
         ></ListBox>
```

The textbox i have should filter out results in real time as you type in it.
So for example you have 5 notes in the listbox, if you search for 'note 2' only that note would be shown, or any other note's that contain 'note 2' in their name.

I know you can do this quite easily with datatable/dataview but i do not know how to set my Itemssource to be the datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing filtering simply by having 3 properties:

1. SearchText
2. Main collection
3. Filtered IEnumerable

**Note so I am using https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged for simpler `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation in the examples (`[AlsoNotifyFor("FilteredItems")]`). You can achieve the same without this library by manually implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged`.**

First of I do bind TextBox to string property:

```
[AlsoNotifyFor("FilteredItems")]
 public string ItemsSearch { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

And bind it like this.

(Note the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` so the binding updates with every button press.)

```
Text="{Binding InventorySearch, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ElementName=UserControl_Main}"
```

Then main collection where I do store all objects:

(You can use ObservableColletion if you plan to add and remove objects in runtime, to update UI more conviniently)

```
[AlsoNotifyFor("FilteredItems")]
 public List<string> Items { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

And at last filtered Enumerable:

```
 public IOrderedEnumerable<string> FilteredItems => 
      Items.Where(x => x.ToUpper().Contains(ItemsSearch.ToUpper()))
```

Comment: Thanks you, took me a bit to figure out how to implement this into my use-case but we got there in the end!